# Apps script - function () { [native code] }

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, function-call

I am making a google apps script and i am trying to make a program that would read the first callendar event. The problem is, when I try to get anything from it it just writes:

> function () { [native code] }.

I have seen some questions written for javascript, but i dont understand, how to add jquery to apps script and i am not sure if it would fix anything.

```
var now = new Date();
var today = new Date(now.getTime());
var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEventsForDay(today);
Logger.log(events);
var event1 = events[0];
Logger.log(event1);
var startTime = event1.getStartTime;
Logger.log(startTime);
var id = event1.getId
Logger.log(id)
var title = event1.getTitle
Logger.log(title)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Explanation:

- The reason you are getting `function () { [native code] }` is because you are not executing the function. Namely, `getStartTime`, `getId`, `getTitle` are not properties but methods (functions). Therefore you need to add `()` at the end e.g. `event1.getStartTime()`.
- You can simply use `var today = new Date()` when specifying the date.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  var today = new Date();
  var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEventsForDay(today);
  var event1 = events[0];
  var startTime = event1.getStartTime(); //modified ()
  Logger.log(startTime);
  var id = event1.getId(); //modified ()
  Logger.log(id);
  var title = event1.getTitle(); //modified ()
  Logger.log(title);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it makes sense, I thaught it was written in different programing language...